# how insert style code between php code

Tags: php, coding-style

i am using wordpress subscribe to comment & i want a hr line after '$message .= __("Comment:\n", 'subscribe-to-comments') . $comment->comment_content . "\n\n";'

if you have some idea please tell me how to style output ? i am new to php

```
if ( $comment->comment_approved == '1' && $comment->comment_type == '' ) {
        // Comment has been approved and isn't a trackback or a pingback, so we should send out notifications

        $message  = sprintf(__("There is a new comment on the post \"%s\"", 'subscribe-to-comments') . ". \n%s\n\n", $post->post_title, get_permalink($comment->comment_post_ID));
        $message .= sprintf(__("Author: %s\n", 'subscribe-to-comments'), $comment->comment_author);
        $message .= __("Comment:\n", 'subscribe-to-comments') . $comment->comment_content . "\n\n";
        $message .= __("See all comments on this post here:\n", 'subscribe-to-comments');
        $message .= get_permalink($comment->comment_post_ID) . "#comments\n\n";
        //add link to manage comment notifications
        $message .= __("To manage your subscriptions or to block all notifications from this site, click the link below:\n", 'subscribe-to-comments');
        $message .= get_settings('home') . '/?wp-subscription-manager=1&email=[email]&key=[key]';

        $subject = sprintf(__('New Comment On: %s', 'subscribe-to-comments'), $post->post_title);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `$message .= '<br />';`